# Best practice build module with different folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

If we can't to import script from parent folder, whats the recommended ways to build our own package good looking and readable in example:

```
my-package/
   firebase/
      __init__.py
      setup.py         #setup the firebase config
      auth.py          #call the setup and handle all of auth user with firebase auth
      firestore.py     #call the setup and handle all data between firestore
   user/
      __init__.py
      user.py          #validate the auth of user
   store/
      __init__.py
      store.py         #crud post and validate the user id with user.py before store to firestore
```

- Where I have `user.py` script that need to use auth module from firebase and also need to store user data to firestore.
- And I have `store.py` to store article data to firestore wichis must be validate the user id from `user.py` before store to firestore.

So `user.py` and `store.py` still need to import auth and firestore from firebase, how to organize the file and import the script from different and other directory?

Comment: Scripts should generally *not* be part of their package. Either they should be executable modules (``python3 -m my_package.store.store``) or separate scripts (``python3 ./store.py``). Use [``entry_points`` ``console_scripts``](https://packaging.python.org/specifications/entry-points/#use-for-scripts) if a package should provide scripts.

Comment: script i mean is python code inside of file

Answer (score 1):

You just need to export your auth.py module class obj in the `__init__.py`

after that you can access that class obj in any folder with help of
`from firebase import cls_obj_name`

Comment: i had try that but its given error ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: We getting error because we are not calling the user from the root package.
Alternatively :  
You can use in user.py
`import os,sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))))
`